# Is there any way to do the preloading of the preroll ad in the Exoplayer?

Tags: ads, exoplayer, google-ad-manager, android-media3, ima

I'm using the IMA ads Extension in ExoPlayer, and I'm facing an issue where ads take some time to load due to internet connectivity or other unforeseen circumstances. To ensure a bufferless video playback experience in Android, I want to precache the IMA ad from the VAST file. While ExoPlayer automatically loads and stores midroll ads in the cache, it doesn't have sufficient time to preload preroll ads. Is there a way to address this issue and precache preroll ads for smoother playback?

The exoplayer has an internal mechanism to load the IMA ads, but for the preroll, I have to do the custom implementation.